# Is it possible to have a repository inside another on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have this problem that has been bothering me for days about my workflow. I freelance on Fiverr and I have a small problem syncing all my different projects I develop for clients between my PCs. To have a better idea of what I am talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXOXN.png) is my file hierarchy

I know I can just initialize a git repo inside the base folder named "Fiverr" but that means whenever I change something to one project and I want to push it to the repo, I will push all the projects. I wanted to have a repo in every project's folder but my GitHub's "Repository" tab will be full of the Fiverr projects. The ideal thing for me would be to keep the same file hierarchy (I have shown you in the picture) for the GitHub as I have it locally, and have a .git file in every project's folder make each one independent of one another.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Create a new [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/about-organizations) and push all your repositories there.

Comment: No, you can't do that (though you can get close as @phd notes) on GitHub. Apparently you *can* organize repositories this way on GitLab. Technically the repositories are not inside the other repositories, they're just organized as a folder hierarchy in the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) mentioned, I got it working the way I wanted by creating an organization. Full credits to him.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).